Android x86 - Blank screen after choose installation from Grub menu
After

Downloaded Android x86 64-bit ISO file from here
Created bootable installer USB drive using Rufus with this specs

Partition scheme : MBR
Target system : BIOS or UEFI
File system : Large FAT32
Cluster size : 32kb


Booted from the USB drive and choose Android Installation from the Grub menu.

Suddenly the screen turned black without no log text displayed like it supposed to. I was stuck there before Ctrl+Alt+Delete restarted the PC.
So I believe I have to manually editing the Grub selection by adding something to it. But I have no idea what am I adding. This is the selection's execution.
setparams 'Android-x86 9.0-r2 Installation' '' 'Android-x86 9.0-r2 Installation' 'INSTALL=1'
savedefault
set root=$android
if [ ! -e $2/kernel ]; then
 search --no-floppy --set root -f $2/kernel
fi
set kd=$2
shift 3
linux $kd/kernel root=/dev/ram0 $src $@
initrd $kd/initrd.img

I just want to at least seeing the log text or successfully boot into Android installation, without no longer stucked with the blank screen.

Do you try to install Android x86 on a physical system or a virtual machine? If it is a physical system what graphic chip is used? The graphic support of Android x86 was as fast I remember always a problem as the number of supported chips wasn't very large and problems not uncommon https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/graphic_card.html

@Robert i believe i tried it physically because i created a boot usb
